# Problems matching the layout with the URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

I'm working on a little project and i have a question.
The website i'm working on is structured like this:
 [image: 3 box layout with pager]
All the sections of the website are in the same document, where on the layout the upper blue part is the menu, and the numbers change the position (using jQuery) of the 1 2 3 divs moving the selected section in the center of it and the others out from the layout.

```
    $("li").click(function() {
    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    if (selectedText == "Upload") {
        $('#homePage').animate({
            left: 2000
        }, 1000);
        $('#upload').animate({
            left: 105
        }, 1000);
        $('#explore').animate({
            left: 2000
        }, 1000);

    }
    if (selectedText == "Gallery") {
        $('#homePage').animate({
            left: 0
        }, 1000);
        $('#upload').animate({
            left: -2000
        }, 1000);
        $('#explore').animate({
            left: 2000
        }, 1000);

    }
    if (selectedText == "Explore") {
        $('#homePage').animate({
            left: -2000
        }, 1000);
        $('#upload').animate({
            left: -4000
        }, 1000);
        $('#explore').animate({
            left: -2000
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

What i need to do now is changing properly the url of the website as i change the section, and  i would like to be able to get to the proper section by the url.
I tried the location.hash method but as i change the hashtag value the jquery animation of the sliding move wrongly the divs (using the same code posted up here having "var selectedText" as the hash value)... I was searching for a solution and i found the HTML5 pushState but i can't really figure out how to use it in my case, since i don't have any AJAX request or anything.
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

To get the URI.

```
document.documentURI
```

And to get the section.

```
var URI = document.documentURI;
var section = URI.substring( URI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 ).replace('.html', '');
```

This will return `foo` from `www.xy.com/foo.html`

Hope I understood your question correct.

Comment: no my question is: what's the best way to have the url matching to the section of the website! Thank you for your answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a GET Variable and this code:

```
    $class="gallery";
if (isset($_GET['p'])){
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    if($p == "explore"){
        $headerActive = $userIsLoggedIn ? 0 : 2;
        $class="explore";
    }
    if($p == "gallery"){
        $headerActive = $userIsLoggedIn ? 0 : 1;
        $class="gallery";
    }
    if($p == "upload"){
        $headerActive = $userIsLoggedIn ? 0 : 0;
        $class="upload";
    }
}
```

and this on the index:

```
<div id="center" style="overflow-x: hidden">
            <div id="content" class="initial-<?= $class?>">
                <?php if($userIsLoggedIn): ?>
                    <? require('templates/submit_form.php') ?>  
                <?php else: ?>
                <div id="uploadform">
                <? require('signin_form.php') ?>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>


                <? require('templates/stickers.php'); ?>
                <? require('templates/explore.php'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS to make it work:

```
#content.initial-gallery #upload {
    left: -2000px;
}

#content.initial-gallery #homePage {
    left: 0px;
}
#content.initial-gallery #explore {
    left: 2000px;
}

#content.initial-upload #upload {
    left: 105px;
}

#content.initial-upload #homePage {
    left: 2000px;
}
#content.initial-upload #explore {
    left: 4000px;
}
#content.initial-explore #upload {
    left: -4000px;
}

#content.initial-explore #homePage {
    left: -2000px;
}
#content.initial-explore #explore {
    left: -2000px;
}
```

Thanks to everybody anyway!